# Prove $\sum_{n = 1}^{p - 1} n^{p - 1} \equiv (p - 1)! + p \pmod {p^2}$ for $p$ being an odd prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I need to prove the following:

> $$\sum_{n = 1}^{p - 1} n^{p - 1} \equiv (p - 1)! + p \pmod {p^2}$$

...with $p$ being an **odd** prime number. The statement is obviously true for$\pmod p$ because left-hand side is congruent to $-1 \pmod p$ by Fermat's little theorem, and the right-hand side also turns out to be congruent to $-1 \pmod p$ by Wilson's theorem. Now, I am not sure how to make a jump from$\pmod p$ to$\pmod {p^2}$, if that is even possible. Maybe the sum on the left could somehow be modified using the existence of the primitive root$\pmod {p^2}$.

EDIT: Elementary solution can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/319824/134054

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes, thanks. I have corrected the formatting

Comment: This is probably true for odd $p$

Comment: My bad, I have corrected the statement. I apologize for that.

Comment: @Oldboy Isn't Fermat's little theorem, only $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ and not for the series?

Comment: @greedoid It isn't in English.

Comment: @toric_actions $n^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}$ for prime $p$. On the left side you have $p-1$ such items so the sum on the left is equal to $(p-1)\times 1\equiv-1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: @Oldboy yeah got it. Thanks.

Comment: The question is now posted also on MathOverflow: [Prove that $\sum_{n = 1}^{p - 1} n^{p - 1} \equiv (p - 1)! + p \pmod {p^2}$ with $p$ being an odd prime](https://mathoverflow.net/q/319805).

Comment: Elementary proof can be found here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/319824/134054

Comment: @Oldboy I've deleted my previous comment : more precisely in the elementary proof, could you please explain the part  $[(p-1)!+1-1]^{p-1}-1\equiv (p-1)[(p-1)!+1](-1)^{p-2}$ ? Thank you !

Comment: @ Oldboy Apologies, I got it now : it is just the two first terms of the binomial expansion since the rest is killed by $mod p^2$. No more question then!